# Diff branches while excluding merge for subversion

Tags: svn, merge, branch, diff

I'm using subversion and I want to diff the start of my branch to the current state of all my files. In addition, I want to exclude certain revisions from the diff. For example, consider the following:

NOTE: treat each character in each file below as a block of code. ("A" is a block of code and "B" is a different block of code)

ID 0: I start with the Trunk:

- File_A (contains "A")
- File_B (contains "B")
- File_C (contains "C")
- File_D (contains "D")

ID 1: I create a branch:

- File_A (contains "A")
- File_B (contains "B")
- File_C (contains "C")
- File_D (contains "D")

ID 2: I modify File_A, File_B, and File_D. I append to File_A and File_B and change the contents of File_D.

- File_A (contains "A1")
- File_B (contains "B1")
- File_C (contains "C")
- File_D (contains "F")

ID 3: I find out that File_B, File_C and File_D has changed in the trunk. The trunk is now:

- File_A (contains "A")
- File_B (contains "B2")
- File_C (contains "C2")
- File_D (contains "E")

ID 4: I then merge from the trunk into my branch:

- File_A (contains "A1")
- File_B (contains "B12")
- File_C (contains "C2")
- File_D (contains "EF")

ID 5: I modify B and C in my branch. Revision is 24015:

- File_A (contains "A1")
- File_B (contains "B123")
- File_C (contains "C3")
- File_D (contains "EF")

Now I want a diff between when I started my branch (ID 1) and when I finished my branch (ID 5) while excluding changes from the merge.

ID 6: I want the diff to show the following:

- File_A (it was "A" and is now "A1" / diff shows "1")
- File_B (it was "B" and is now "B13" / diff shows "13")
- File_C (it was "C" and is now "C3" / diff shows "3")
- File_D (it was "D" and is now "F" / diff shows all differences between D and F)

I want create a patch file that contains the changes for the four files above. So when applied to ID 1, I get ID 6. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two obvious ways**

- **Short way**: `svn help diff`, 4-th form. Just diff heads of branch and trunk: identical hunks in both sides (`A`,`C2`,`B`) will be skipped (you'll effectively ignore mergesets, if they only performed merges without edits)
- **Dumb way, as requested**: `svn help diff`, 2-nd form with `-c` option. You'll diff branch (start of branch or HEAD - can't recall from mind and too lazy to test) with multiple use `-c REV` in order to enumerate *all revisions in branch without* mergeset(s)

Textually diffs may be slightly different, because SVN's unified diff work in context (3 lines around hunk by default) and for "thin" changes it will (may be) visible